# Проблема с чтением всех файлов в директории

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, tkinter

Возникла проблема с чтением всех файлов из директории. С помощью tkinter передается путь до папки откуда брать файлы, однако вылетает с ошибкой

> FileNotFoundError: [Error 2] No such file or directory: 'filename.csv'

Код который использую:

```py
def readf(self):
   for r, d, f in os.walk(self.name_m.get()):
      for filepath in f:
          with open(filepath, 'r') as csvFile:
              reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
              m = np.array([])
                 for row in reader:
                    m = np.append(m, float(row[0])
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь прочитать первый столбец из всех CSV файлов и объединить все это в один 1D вектор? Я правильно понимаю ваш код?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял ваше намерение и вы пытаетесь прочитать первый столбец из всех CSV файлов из всех поддиректорий по укзанному пути и объединить все это в один 1D вектор, то это можно сделать проще и элегантнее:

```
import pandas as pd      #   pip install pandas
from pathlib import Path

def readf(self, path):
    path = Path(path)
    data = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, usecols=[0], header=None) 
                      for f in path.glob("**")])
    return data.values.ravel()
```

Answer (score 0):

В переменную `f` у вас попадают просто имена файлов без путей. Чтобы открыть файл, к имени нужно добавлять путь:

```
def readf(self):
    for current_directory, dirs, files in os.walk(self.name_m.get()):
        for filename in files:
            with open(os.path.join(current_directory, filename), 'r') as csvFile:
                reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
```